# Sending customize extension file through attachment in MMS

Tags: android, android-sharing, android-sms

I have a customize extension file which i'm saving in internal memory let's say file.abc, everything is working fine and i'm able to share it through every messenger but can't attach it to sms as it's not media file i thought.Is there any solution to attach this file in sms?